# Javascript: Why doesn't .toString() reveal code for some functions?

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, sleep, tostring

I just installed `sleep` Node.js module and have implemented in my code. When I try the following code `console.log(sleep.usleep.toString());` the result shows `[native code]` instead of the actual code inside `usleep()`, but when I try the same thing on my functions, it includes all the code in the return value of `.toString()`:

```
function a() {
    //code
}
console.log(a.toString());
```

How come `.toString()` doesn't reveal the code inside `sleep.usleep()`?

Comment: Not 100% sure, but I usually get [native code] when I toString() methods defined on a prototype.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[Native code]` means that it's a function implemented in the javascript engine of your browser in `native` code and not in `javascript`.